# Two (or more) consecutive newlines in String in Android

Tags: java, android, line, break, separator

I need to add in a String several line breaks, but does not work, it only adds the first line break. But in java it works.

For example, for this String:

```
String s = "one\n\ntwo";
```

prints in android:

```
one
two
```

In java prints:

```
one

two
```

I tested with "\n", "System.getProperty("line.separator") and String.format("%n") whith the same result.

Does anyone know a solution?

UPDATE: I generate dynamically the String to authenticate against a server, I have no need to add it to a TextView and I can not use strings.xml

SOLVED: Logcat does not print lines only with \n, but the string contains it. Thanks.

Comment: are you print in logcat or in textview ?

Comment: Try to set text in textview and see you achieve your result.

Comment: from your below comments I suggest you rephrase your question to include what you are trying to achieve and what your limitations are.

Comment: @jlordo I updated the question a few minutes more, although it was quite clear what he asked.

Comment: Than we don't understand your question. This `\n\n` are two new lines. What is your problem with that?

Comment: My problem whith that is only adds the first line break

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
String s = "one \n \n two";
```

before & after newline(\n) leave some space then it will work

Comment: Use the String to authenticate against a server and I can not set blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your string in string.xml file like this way

```
<string name="test">one\n\n\ntwo</string>
```

it show as you wise.

thanks

Comment: That's not valid for me, I generate dynamically the String to authenticate against a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textId1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#ff4500" />
```

From your Activty:

```
String s = "one\n\ntwo";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId1);        
tv.setText(s);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not valid for me, I generate dynamically the String to authenticate against a server.

Comment: @alfonsomiranda be specific with your requirements while you are posting question.

Answer (score 0):

try  adding `<br>`or`<br/>` instead of \n.